# Windows disk usage issues with python

Tags: python, windows, disk

I am executing the python code that follows.

I am running it on a folder ("articles") which has a couple hundred subfolders and 240,226 files in all.

I am timing the execution. At first the times were pretty stable but went non-linear after 100,000 files. Now the times (I am timing at 10,000 file intervals) can go non_linear after 30,000 or so (or not).

I have the Task Manager open and correlate the slow-downs to 99% Disk usage by python.exe. I have done gc-collect(). dels etc., turned off Windows indexing. I have re-started Windows, emptied the trash (I have a few hundred GBs free). Nothing helps, the disk usage seems to be getting more erratic if anything.

Sorry for the long post - Thanks for the help

```
def get_filenames():
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk("articles/"):
        dirs.extend(dirnames)

    for dir in dirs:
        path = "articles" + "\\" + dir        
        nxml_files.extend(glob.glob(path + "/*.nxml"))

    return nxml_files

def extract_text_from_files(nxml_files):  
    for nxml_file in nxml_files:       
        fast_parse(nxml_file)

def fast_parse(infile):
    file = open(infile,"r")
    filetext = file.read()
    tag_breaks = filetext.split('><')
    paragraphs = [tag_break.strip('p>').strip('</') for tag_break in tag_breaks if tag_break.startswith('p>')]

def run_files(): 
    nxml_files = get_filenames()
    extract_text_from_files(nxml_files)

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    run_files()
```

Comment: If you can, upgrade to Python 3.5; your code doesn't seem to use specific version features, and `os.walk` got reimplemented using the new [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) function. Though `os.walk` doesn't provide the free `stat` information to you through its interface, it performs far less disk I/O; on Python <=3.4, it had to read in the complete list of files (a small handful of I/O ops with limited seeking), then `stat` them all to separate files and directories (in your case ~100,000 random reads). Using `os.scandir` eliminates the ~100,000 `stats`.

Comment: According to the [Python 3.5 release notes](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-471), `os.scandir`'s use in `os.walk` seamlessly improves the speed of `os.walk` on Windows systems by 7-20x. That's huge, and if you're scanning over a hundred thousand files, you'd almost certainly benefit from the speed up.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things that could be optimized.

At first, is you open files, close them as well. A `with open(...) as name:` block will do that easily. BTW in Python 2 `file` is a bad choice for a variable name, it is built-in function's name.

You can remove one disc read by doing string comparisons instead of the glob.

And last but not least: `os.walk` spits out the results cleverly, so don't buffer them into a list, process everything inside one loop. This will save a lot of memory.

That is what I can advise from the code. For more details on what is causing the I/O you should use profiling. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html for details.

Comment: Another opportunity to reduce disk I/O: `os.walk` gives a list of `filenames` which are discarded, and `glob.glob` is used to get a filtered set of the files, when [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html) could be used to filter `filenames` directly and avoid the redundant disk I/O involved in `glob.glob`. Edit: Oops, I see you mentioned that. Leaving this here for the link to `fnmatch` (which is what `glob.glob` actually uses for the filtering, so it can simulate `glob` precisely on a known list of file names).

Comment: Yes, that would be an alternative to what I wrote. I leave it to the OP to test which is faster and more suitable.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, did them all, the same behavior on disk (notice in code getting the filenames is a one time hit) I think the major question is why is the extract_text_from_files code (even with a file.close()) erratically sucking up Disk??